# What does the 'resources :controller_name' do in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Pretty new and taking my basic grasp in this language.

What does the "**resource**" keyword exactly do in the routes.rb file?

Comment: read docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Don't confuse `resource` with `resources`. [resource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource)

Answer (score 0):

if in very simple way:

```
resources :user do
  resource :profile
end
```

means that you have many `users` and you can get it by `/users/1`, `users/2`, etc, but each `user` have just one `profile` and you can get it by `/users/1/profile`

and `users` have all standard actions like `index`, `new`, `show`, `create`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy`
and `profile` has same, but `index`

you should read more deeper [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)